# merging pdf files without keeping the pdf files in the same folder

Tags: pdftex

I would like to merge some pdf files, for example, paper1 & paper2. But they are in some other folders. I just want to run the tex file without keeping the pdf files. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: So you don't want to add anything, just merge the files into one? For this you can also just use [The PDF Toolkit](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)...

Comment: are you using `\includepdf` ? if so you can simply state the full location of each of the files, for instance `\includepdf{c:\place\where\first\file\is\paper1.pdf}`

Answer (score 1):

At least two options here:

1. Use [The PDF Toolkit](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to merge the input PDFs into a single file.

   From the [examples page](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/), you can merge `in1.pdf` and `in2.pdf` into a single `out1.pdf`:

   ```
   pdftk in1.pdf in2.pdf cat output out1.pdf
   ```

   The PDF Toolkit also provides a GUI for doing this.
2. [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) provides the capability to insert PDFs as-is in your document. Similar to the above example, you could use the following:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pdfpages}
   \begin{document}
   \includepdf[pages=-]{in1}% in1.pdf
   \includepdf[pages=-]{in2}% in2.pdf
   \end{document}
   ```